# Does google cloud vision OCR support bar code reading?

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm building an application which utilizes google cloud platform's OCR service. I'm still in progress with it and just wanted to know if this service also detects the bar codes and decode them?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

No--requiring users to have a network connection just to read a barcode would be excessive, and too slow. Check out the [Google Mobile Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview) instead, which runs on the device.