# How can I call or emulate Google Mobile Vision API in Google Cloud?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, pdf417

Background: Building on [Does google cloud vision OCR support bar code reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309709/does-google-cloud-vision-ocr-support-bar-code-reading), I *want* to do offline analysis of PDF417 barcodes using Google Mobile Vision (Barcode API) but accessible from Google Cloud.

Is there any way to call, emulate or otherwise access the Google Mobile Vision API off-Android/off-iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rolling a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to detect QR codes for images loaded into Google Cloud Storage, which handled the use case where, like you, I would have preferred to use Cloud Vision. You could do something similar with a HTTP Cloud Function that sends over an image, and uses a [JS library](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/js-zxing-pdf417) to read the barcodes.